# python: while statment with several boolean tests

Tags: python, boolean-logic

A local elementary school has library card IDs of the following form: IDs either begin with "s" (for "student") and are exactly 6 characters long, including the "s"; or they begin with "t" (for "teacher") and have no length requirement. The following function is supposed to get a valid ID, but it is missing its while condition.

```
def get_valid_id():
    '''Prompt the user for and return a valid library card ID.'''

    s = raw_input("Enter ID: ")
    while ?????:
        s = raw_input("Try again: ")
    return s
```

Below are some possible conditions for the while loop. For each, indicate whether it will make the function work correctly.

1. Will this condition make the function work correctly?
   `(s[0] != "s") and (len(s) != 6) and (s[0] != "t")`
2. Will this condition make the function work correctly?
   `not( (s[0] == "s" and len(s) == 6) or (s[0] == "t") )`

I don't get why the answer for 1 is no and 2 is yes. I thought the first question would work since it's all "and", and the second question I thought the "or" wouldn't make it work.. could someone please explain this to me?

Comment: We didn't learn that in class. I'm in a beginner level class for python.

Comment: homework? It's fine it if is, we should just tag it as such.

Comment: DeMorgan's Law is a law of boolean logic, which you can study even if you never go anywhere near programming. Check it out on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As someone commented, [DeMorgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

> not (A or B or C) = (not A) and (not B) and (not C)

It's also easier to think about when you consider that `not not A = A`, so that the statement you need is `while not X` where `X` is a test for a *good* id.

So the first case will translate to

```
 not ( (s[0] != "s") or (len(s) != 6) or (s[0] != "t") )
```

i.e. the id passes of *any* of the above sub-statements are true, so *just* `s[0] != "s"` would be sufficient.

In the second case,

```
not( (s[0] == "s" and len(s) == 6) or (s[0] == "t") )
```

means the id passes if *either* `(s[0] == "s" and len(s) == 6)` (student criteria) *or* `s[0] == "t"` (teacher criteria).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation Shep.

Comment: @alicew no problem, even experienced programmers stumble over boolian logic, it's important that you spend some time scratching your head and looking at it now.

Answer (score 2):

This is because **1** will accept student id's of length < 6. According to your question, student id's *must* be 6 characters long, including the s. Also note that both options will break if you attempt to enter an empty string. `s[0]` will raise an `IndexError`.